# How can I count the number of times an item appears in a JSON object? Django

Tags: python, json, django, python-3.x

I developed the following code to extract data from a web API and I am trying to manipulate it based on the following condition: *Count the number of times that users appear between dates initial date which is current time -
6 days and final date is current time.*

The JSON object that I receive has the following structure:

```
[{
id: 1003384,
user_id : 0001
CreatedOn: "2017-02-16 15:54:48",
Problem: "AVAILABILILTY",
VIP: "YES",
Vendor_CODE: "XYZ12345",
Week_id: "07",
},
{
id: 1003338,
user_id: 0002
CreatedOn: "2017-02-15 13:49:16",
Problem: "AVAILABILILTY",
VIP: "NO",
Vendor_CODE: "XYZ67890",
Week_id: "09",
},
{
id: 1553338,
user_id: 0002
CreatedOn: "2017-03-15 09:30:36",
Problem: "AVAILABILILTY",
VIP: "YES",
Vendor_CODE: "ACE67890",
Week_id: "13",
}]
```

Now, when I execute the following code I cannot count the number of times the users appears between given two dates because I get the error keys should be integers not strings and I do not know where should I implement the initial and final dates.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json, urllib.request
from collections import Counter

#Request a response to the Web API
def get_data(request, *args, **kwargs):
    # YYYY-MM-DD
    start_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=7)
    end_date = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=1) 

    with urllib.request.urlopen("http://10.61.202.98:8081/T/ansdb/api/rows/triage/ect/tickets",timeout=15) as url:
    response_data = json.loads(url.read().decode())

    #verify that you receive data in your terminal
    print(response_data[0]) 

    # The JSON object should be manipulated as a dictionary but this is not the case
    user_times = Counter(k['user_id'] for k in response_data if k.get('user_id'))

    return JsonResponse(response_data, safe=False)
```

In order to avoid the error keys should be integers not string I use print(response_data[0]) to get the output:

```
{
id: 1003384,
user_id : 0001
CreatedOn: "2017-02-16 15:54:48",
Problem: "AVAILABILILTY",
VIP: "YES",
Vendor_CODE: "XYZ12345",
Week_id: "07",
}
```

My questions are:

1. Is my JSON data a dictionary once I parsed it with json.loads(url.read().decode())? If so, why I cannot retrieve data as response_data['user_id'] to see all the users?
2. What is missing to the code to count the number of times that user appears in order to be working?
3. Where should I implement the dates code to retrieve the users by given dates?

Thanks in advance, please feel free to suggest any ideas to this post.

**Updates** 
**June 06, 2017**

1. The JSON data that I parsed is a dictionary and I can validate it because I used print(isinstance(response_data[0],dict)) and the result is True.
2. I tried to print the keys from this dictionary with print(response_data.keys()) but **I encountered this error: list object has no attribute 'keys'. How is this possible** if Python states that this is a dictionary but I cannot print the keys?

Comment: instead of printing, try this `isinstance(response_data[0], dict)` to check if it is really a dictionary and post the result please

Comment: I did print(isinstance(response_data[0],dict)) and the result is True.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First**: You cannot do `response_data['user_id']` because `response_data` is a list. So, you have to do `response_data[0]['user_id']`.

**Second**: Your code should be inside a list comprehension:

```
Counter([k['user_id'] for k in response_data if k.get('user_id')])
```

**Third**: You should implement it in your list comprehension which will look something like this:

```
Counter([k['user_id'] for k in response_data if k.get('user_id') and start_date < dateutil.parser.parse(k.get('CreatedOn')) < end_date])
```

You should install [dateutil](https://dateutil.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) for the third to work. Or use any other way to convert string to datetime.

Hope it helps!

Comment: How is that response_data is a list when the isinstance() states that this is a dictionary?

Comment: @AlejandroRamos Did you do `isinstance(response_data[0], dict)` or `isinstance(response_data, dict)`?

Comment: And in your question, it looks like a list of dictionaries: `[{dict_1}, {dict_2}, {dict_3}]`

Comment: When I used isinstance(response_data[0], dict) I got True but when I used isinstance(response_data, dict) I got false which is the answer of your last comment. Did I parse correctly the JSON to a Dictionary? Do you know how can I simplify this data structure?

Comment: @AlejandroRamos if response_data is a list and response_data[0] is a dict, then you parsed the JSON correctly. But not to a dict. To a list of dicts. And it is OK. Apply my suggestions and you should be good. If some errors comes up, please post it.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jahongir! I used some of your suggestions and I came up with this: 
user_id = [value['user_id'] for value in response_data]
    print(user_id)
I will keep you posted about this post, besides, the final solution has not been implemented yet.

Comment: Sure, just let me implement the changes into my code.